# Что такое custom editor?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я новичок по unity, недавно столкнулся с конструкцией custom editor. Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, что это такое?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Кнопка]

CustomEditor позволяет изменять внешний вид скрипта, например добавлять кнопки, галочки и т.д.

Самый простой MonoBehaviour скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int num;
}
```

Скрипт CustomEditor:

```
using UnityEditor;
//Пишем атрибут и даём ему MyClass.
[CustomEditor(typeof(MyClass))]
public class MyClassEditor : Editor
{
    //Вызываем метод для отрисовки 
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
        //Объявляем переменную для доступа к классу 
        var myClass = (target) as MyClass;

        //Рисуем кнопку 
        if (GUILayout.Button("Add Num"))
        {
            //Соответственно делаем что хотим.
            myClass.num += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Помимо GUILayout.Button() есть и другие, посмотрите список здесь:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayout.html

Так же:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.html

Comment: Спасибо, но я не очень хорошо понимаю, где это может примениться на практике

Comment: @Viktor, На практике это нужно для написании плагинов где нужен более менее красивый интерфейс или упрощение каких либо задач по разработке.

Comment: спасибо вам огромное!