# Отображения класса unity в инспекторе

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть класс Dict, обычный словарь. Но я хочу сделать для него удобное отображение в инспекторе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что можно сделать, чтобы вместо первого получить что-то на подобии второго?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот полный код класса

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class Dict
{
    [SerializeField] public DictElement[] _dictElements;
    [SerializeField] public Vector3[] vec;
}

[Serializable]
public class DictElement
{
    [SerializeField] public playerStats key;
    [SerializeField] public float value;
    public DictElement(){}
}
```

Comment: Вы не написали в вопросе самое главное - вопрос

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2018.4/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html   ....  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-HowTo-CreateCustomInspector.html 
 ...........  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1511753/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-custom-editor

Answer (score 1):

Для решения вашей проьлемы подойдет использование PropertyDrawer в котором ваш елемент списка будет отображать все поля елемента в одной строчке с фиксированными размерами. Пример такого PropwrtyDrawer вы можете найти в [этом посте форума](https://forum.unity.com/threads/building-a-custom-property-drawer-for-serializable-class.1244857/#post-7923157).

Если же вы можете приобрести платные ассеты в Asset Store то предлагаю выложиться и купить один раз на всю жизнь полезный инструмент который упростит жизнь разработки кастомных редакторов - Odin Inspector.